# What was the importance of the Liars Paradox in Stoic Logic?

Tags: logic, epistemology, history-of-philosophy, paradox, ancient-philosophy

[Chrysippus](http://www.iep.utm.edu/chrysipp/), an influential stoic philosopher wrote 21 books (chapters) in 12 works on the Liars Paradox. This implies that this paradox was of some importance to their epistomology and logic. Why?

Comment: How do you infer that the liar's paradox was "central" to stoic epistemology and logic? (Please keep in mind that the ancient notion of "book" is equivalent to our notion of "chapter".)

Comment: Good point. I'll rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the (old but still authoritative) book of Benson Mates, [Stoic Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=3jmQoAEACAAJ) (University of California Press, 1953) at pag.84, on the Liar Paradox in Stoic Logic.